# My wireless interface can't see access point

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm trying to learn how to manage wireless with my Ubuntu and so what I want to do is to enable my wireless from command line.

What I have done is this:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

I have only one cell so what I do is to take the associated ESSID.

The next step is to assign `wlan0` interface to that ESSID to communicate with access point. And so what I do is this:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid <ESSID-value>
```

Now if I check `iwconfig` of `wlan0` I should have an assigned ESSID and an assigned access point but seems that only ESSID is assigned and access point is not associated.

What's wrong? Looking for examples I see that `iwlist` scanning produces different Cells, why to me there is only one?

Comment: Is WiFi access point password protected? Then use sequence: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid <ESSID-value> key s:12345` and later `sudo dhclient wlan0` .Replace **12345** with your password

Comment: ok thanks for the help, now seems that access point is associated but when i do sudo dhclient wlan0 my terminal seems to sleep and don't give me an ip

Comment: Alex's comment only works for WEP security: do you happen to have WPA2-PSK security instead?

Comment: Yes, @MariusMatutiae are right, all `iw` commands doesn't support WPA. I assumed OP read `man iwconfig` that's why he wanted to use `iw` cmds. If access point set with WPA(2) encryption, then you need `wpasupplicant`.